# sortrows does not sort properly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am trying to sort a group of arrays in matlab, but the function sortrows doesn't do this properly.

I am sorting on the first and second columns.

An example of this is the following

```
X = [0         0    0.0000
         0    0.2500   -0.3347
    0.2500    0.2500    0.0010
    0.2500         0    0.3357
         0    0.5000   -0.0000
    0.2500    0.5000    0.3357
         0    0.7500    0.3347
    0.2500    0.7500    0.6704
         0    1.0000    0.0000
    0.2500    1.0000    0.3357
    0.5000    0.2500   -0.3347
    0.5000         0    0.0000
    0.5000    0.5000   -0.0000
    0.5000    0.7500    0.3347
    0.5000    1.0000    0.0000
    0.7500    0.2500   -0.6704
    0.7500         0   -0.3357
    0.7500    0.5000   -0.3357
    0.7500    0.7500   -0.0010
    0.7500    1.0000   -0.3357
    1.0000    0.2500   -0.3347
    1.0000         0    0.0000
    1.0000    0.5000   -0.0000
    1.0000    0.7500    0.3347
    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000]

X_sorted = sortrows(X,[1 2])

X_sorted = [0         0    0.0000
             0    0.2500   -0.3347
             0    0.5000   -0.0000
             0    0.7500    0.3347
             0    1.0000    0.0000
        0.2500    0.2500    0.0010
        0.2500    0.5000    0.3357
        0.2500    0.7500    0.6704
        0.2500         0    0.3357
        0.2500    1.0000    0.3357
        0.5000    0.2500   -0.3347
        0.5000    0.5000   -0.0000
        0.5000    0.7500    0.3347
        0.5000         0    0.0000
        0.5000    1.0000    0.0000
        0.7500         0   -0.3357
        0.7500    1.0000   -0.3357
        0.7500    0.2500   -0.6704
        0.7500    0.5000   -0.3357
        0.7500    0.7500   -0.0010
        1.0000         0    0.0000
        1.0000    0.2500   -0.3347
        1.0000    0.5000   -0.0000
        1.0000    0.7500    0.3347
        1.0000    1.0000    0.0000]
```

Now, how you can see in the example, the function is sorting on the first column, but is not doing it on the second one.

I'm using Matlab 2018b

My desired result is:

```
 X_sorted = [0         0    0.0000
             0    0.2500   -0.3347
             0    0.5000   -0.0000
             0    0.7500    0.3347
             0    1.0000    0.0000
        0.2500         0    0.3357
        0.2500    0.2500    0.0010
        0.2500    0.5000    0.3357
        0.2500    0.7500    0.6704
        0.2500    1.0000    0.3357
        0.5000         0    0.0000
        0.5000    0.2500   -0.3347
        0.5000    0.5000   -0.0000
        0.5000    0.7500    0.3347
        0.5000    1.0000    0.0000
        0.7500         0   -0.3357
        0.7500    0.2500   -0.6704
        0.7500    0.5000   -0.3357
        0.7500    0.7500   -0.0010
        0.7500    1.0000   -0.3357
        1.0000         0    0.0000
        1.0000    0.2500   -0.3347
        1.0000    0.5000   -0.0000
        1.0000    0.7500    0.3347
        1.0000    1.0000    0.0000]
```

Comment: What's the desired result? Do you want to sort rows atomically, or to sort the elements within each row?

Comment: Ah, I completely missed the error. It would be helpful if you could point out where the incorrect entries are. Are you initializing `X` as shown in your example, or are the values generated by some previous code. One thing I can think of that would cause this is that the values in the first column are not actually the same, but are rounded to the same values for display.

Comment: The error es in the second row, for example when the first row is equal to 0.2500, the second one has the order 0.2500, 0.5000, 0.7500, 0, 1.

Comment: Are you using the word "row" to refer to "columns" by any chance? Please indicate what the expected output is. Your code is sorting the rows in lexicographical order based on the first and second columns. It leaves each row unchanged. just in a different position

Answer (score 2):

Use `format long`, then look at the values in the first column again. Likely they are very similar but not identical values.

One way around this problem is to round the numbers in the array to 4 decimal digits:

```
X = round(X,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s something not right here, here’s what I get using MATLAB R2020a:

```
>> sortrows(X,[1,2])

ans =

     0         0         0
     0    0.2500   -0.3347
     0    0.5000         0
     0    0.7500    0.3347
     0    1.0000         0
0.2500         0    0.3357
0.2500    0.2500    0.0010
0.2500    0.5000    0.3357
0.2500    0.7500    0.6704
0.2500    1.0000    0.3357
0.5000         0         0
0.5000    0.2500   -0.3347
0.5000    0.5000         0
0.5000    0.7500    0.3347
0.5000    1.0000         0
0.7500         0   -0.3357
0.7500    0.2500   -0.6704
0.7500    0.5000   -0.3357
0.7500    0.7500   -0.0010
0.7500    1.0000   -0.3357
1.0000         0         0
1.0000    0.2500   -0.3347
1.0000    0.5000         0
1.0000    0.7500    0.3347
1.0000    1.0000         0
```

As you can see the second column is being sorted correctly. What version of MATLAB are you using? Are you sure you don’t have a version of `sorrows` on your path shadowing the built-in version? (check with `which sortrows`)

Comment: Good eye. I missed the unsorted values the first time around.

Comment: I am using Matlab 2018b.

Comment: When I write `which sortrows` I get this: C:\\Program Files\Matlab\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\sortrows.p

Comment: I just checked again using R2018b, pasting the exact code from your question, and got the same result as I posted above. So I still don't know what's going on - you might wish to consider reinstalling MATLAB, or contacting MathWorks support.